# decompose complex sentences to simple sentences

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, decomposition

Having a sentence like: "I was given tablets by my nurse to try and ease my pain." I want to decompose it to:

1. "I was given tablets by my nurse to try."
2. "I was given tablets by my nurse to ease my pain."

I have tried English parser in OpenNLP (by accessing java from Python) (demo: http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/parser/index.jsp). "try" and "ease" are at the same sub-level of (VP (TO to) below, how can I decompose the sentence?

```
(ROOT
  (S
    (NP (PRP I))
    (VP (VBD was)
      (VP (VBN given)
        (NP (NNS tablets))
        (PP (IN by)
          (NP (PRP$ my) (NN nurse)
            (S
              (VP (TO to)
                (VP (VB try)
                  (CC and)
                  (VB ease)
                  (NP (PRP$ my) (NN pain)))))))))
    (. .)))
```

Do you know any way other than this java solution: [algorithm to extract simple sentences from complex(mixed) sentences?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10020451/algorithm-to-extract-simple-sentences-from-complexmixed-sentences)

Comment: I'm not sure why you want to decompose it like that, but those two shorter sentences mean something different to me than the one longer sentence.

Comment: I want to do sentiment analysis. As you see there are 2 main reasons to use the tablet : 

1- to try 

2- to ease the pain. 

I want to break the sentence in order to have each reason in a separate sentence.
The joiner **and** is the indicator here.

Comment: Except to my ear, "try and ease the pain" is not two things: it's one attempt to ease the pain. It would be the same as saying, "I was given tablets by my nurse to try to ease the pain"

Comment: As far as I can see, *try* and *ease* are at the same level in the Stanford output tree.

Comment: Right, my mistake, I edited my post.